# How to read a .bib file in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a .bib file and i want to read its content in c++ through code. Basically i am writting the code so what ever .bib file i give it. It could extract data as an text content or something from it.

I know how to read, write the .txt file, And I have used the same method for the .bib file but that's not working. Following is the Code i tried.

```
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
```

I expect to read the .bib file as an text content or something so i can extract data from it and also do some searching. Any help would be really appreciated thanks.

Comment: What's a .bib file (A BibTeX bibliography file or something else?) Is there anything that documents its format? If so, start by reading that.

Comment: How can a .bib file be named "example.txt"?

Comment: A .bib file is a text file. Interpreting the content is another story. What problem do you have exactly?

Comment: Yes .bib file is a bibliography file.

Comment: example.txt was to demonstrate the method i have used to read text files.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ doesn't care about file extensions. If the `.bib` files are text files, just open them like any other text file specifying the full name (which includes the `.bib` extension):

```
ofstream myfile("example.bib");
```

`std::ofstream` is in text mode by default so your file would be treated as a text file.

If `.bib` files aren't text files, you would have to read the documentation about its format and learn how to read binary files.